# Ansible playbook with no default hosts

Tags: ansible

I want to build a potentially dangerous Ansible playbook. To make it marginally safer, I don't want any default hosts.

Is there a way to specify no hosts in an Ansible playbook and require users to enter them on the command line?

Answer (score 2):

Playbook:

```
- host: {{ my_danger_host }}
  tasks:
```

Command:

```
ansible-playbtook -i hosts deploy.yml  -extra-vars my_danger_host=10.45.130.56
```

Answer (score -1):

```
- host: {{ my_danger_host }}
  tasks: 
    - name : check_host
      fail :
        msg : "please input host"
      when : (my_danger_host is not defined)
```